# How do I remove duplicates from a struct slice?

Tags: go, struct, slice

I have a struct like this:

```golang
type structData struct {
      dataName string
      dataNum int
}
```

And I have created a slice out of them, like so:

```golang
dataSlice := []*structData{}
```

I have a loop that populates the `dataName` string and just after this, I want the struct slice to be checked through and duplicates removed.
I mention this specifically because currently, `dataNum` is 0. So, I don't want to check if the string inside my struct is same or not, it is totally fine checking if the entire struct is equal (if that's possible, else it is also OKAY for me to check duplicates in the `dataName` string, I just don't know what would look better in design).

An example output of what my struct slice looks like:

```golang
&{dataname1 0}
&{dataname1 0}
&{dataname2 0}
&{dataname2 0}
```

What I want it to look like:

```golang
&{dataname1 0}
&{dataname2 0}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problem(s) did you run into?

Comment: I've tried making maps but they haven't worked out, as in, I don't get any error but duplicates aren't removed. Perhaps, I wasn't using maps with structs properly but I'm not sure, I don't understand structs properly, so I dropped that idea thinking that it just wouldn't work.

Comment: Please update your question to show the code you tried and detail what problems you encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a map to check for duplicates, where your struct is the key to the map.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type structData struct {
    dataName string
    dataNum  int
}

func (d *structData) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("(%s,%d)", d.dataName, d.dataNum)
}

func main() {
    dataSlice := []*structData{
        {"dataname1", 0},
        {"dataname1", 0},
        {"dataname2", 0},
        {"dataname2", 0},
    }
    m := map[structData]struct{}{}
    dataSlice2 := []*structData{}
    for _, d := range dataSlice {
        if _, ok := m[*d]; !ok {
            dataSlice2 = append(dataSlice2, d)
            m[*d] = struct{}{}
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", dataSlice)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", dataSlice2)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/wL-SfBCMGQj